# Changin the base URL of loopback lb-services.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loopbackjs

I´m trying to get a client server and a rest api server to connect. I´m using angular js on frontend and loopback on backend.

on the lb-services.js I changed base url to:

```
  var urlBase = 'http://localhost:3000/api';
```

My angular js is running on port 4000. But when I make a post to the rest api I get this error on my browser:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/api/People. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

Is there anyway I can proxy the connection or make both servers work together properly?

This is my gulp/server.js:

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var conf = require('./conf');

var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var browserSyncSpa = require('browser-sync-spa');

var util = require('util');

var proxyMiddleware = require('http-proxy-middleware');

function browserSyncInit(baseDir, browser) {
  browser = browser === undefined ? 'default' : browser;

  var routes = null;
  if(baseDir === conf.paths.src || (util.isArray(baseDir) && baseDir.indexOf(conf.paths.src) !== -1)) {
    routes = {
      '/bower_components': 'bower_components'
    };
  }

  var server = {
    baseDir: baseDir,
    routes: routes
  };

  /*
   * You can add a proxy to your backend by uncommenting the line below.
   * You just have to configure a context which will we redirected and the target url.
   * Example: $http.get('/users') requests will be automatically proxified.
   *
   * For more details and option, https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/blob/v0.9.0/README.md
   */
   server.middleware = proxyMiddleware('/api', {
     target: 'http://localhost:3000/api',
     changeOrigin: true

   });

  browserSync.instance = browserSync.init({
    startPath: '/',
    server: server,
    browser: browser,
    port:4000
  });
}

browserSync.use(browserSyncSpa({
  selector: '[ng-app]'// Only needed for angular apps
}));

gulp.task('serve', ['watch'], function () {
  browserSyncInit([path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve'), conf.paths.src]);
});

gulp.task('serve:dist', ['build'], function () {
  browserSyncInit(conf.paths.dist);
});

gulp.task('serve:e2e', ['inject'], function () {
  browserSyncInit([conf.paths.tmp + '/serve', conf.paths.src], []);
});

gulp.task('serve:e2e-dist', ['build'], function () {
  browserSyncInit(conf.paths.dist, []);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway I can proxy the connection or make both servers work
>   together properly?

It's surprising that you get this error as loopback enables CORS by default. It would be worth checking out the middleware.json file in your loopback server and see whether cors.params.origin is true. [Here](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/middleware.json) is the documentation link for your reference.

I'm not sure how you have changed the urlBase for accessing your rest api. I had done it using the angular module config as described [here](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/AngularJS+JavaScript+SDK#AngularJSJavaScriptSDK-Clientconfiguration).

Answer (score 0):

You can add CORS support to your LoopBack API:

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Security+considerations#Securityconsiderations-CORS